# Azure service bus configuration via code spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using the following dependency to send and receive messages from a azure service bus topic:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'd like to create the configuration via code through a spring bean because I need to configure more than 1 connection string, so after read the documentation, I decided to create this bean:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AzureServiceBusJmsProperties priceListJmsProperties() {
        var properties = new AzureServiceBusJmsProperties();
        properties.setConnectionString(connectionString);
        properties.setPricingTier("standard");
        properties.setTopicClientId(priceListTopicName);
        return properties;
    }
```

If I debug the object creation, I see that this object is been creating twice, the first one with the configuration that I've provided, and the second one with null data, and this is the reason of why I'm getting the following error because there is a validation in this object that throws an exception if certain field is not set in the properties file:

```
spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string' should be provided
```

I've tried creating a connection factory instead but for the reason above, I'm getting the same error.

Anyone knows how I can set this configuration as a bean instead of the `application.properties` file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Spring JMS Servicebus does not have spring.jms.servicebus.enabled property](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/29232) and [How to use the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Service Bus JMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I couldn't disable the jms autoconfiguration with that property, also I'm using a different dependency, but that issue helped me to solve my problem, I just excluded the `ServiceBusJmsAutoConfiguration` class from the autoconfiguration. So thank you for posting that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @DeepDave-MT answer, I couldn't disable the jms autoconfiguration with the `spring.jms.servicebus.enabled` property, so I decided to exclude the `ServiceBusJmsAutoConfiguration` with the property `spring.autoconfigure.exclude`, you have to pass the package name to this property.

Then, in my config class, I just added the following beans:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        var connectionFactory = new ServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory(connectionString);
        var serviceBusConnectionString = new ServiceBusConnectionString(connectionString);
        var remoteUri = String.format(AMQP_URI_FORMAT, serviceBusConnectionString.getEndpointUri(), 100000);
        connectionFactory.setRemoteURI(remoteUri);
        connectionFactory.setClientID(topicName);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(serviceBusConnectionString.getSharedAccessKeyName());
        connectionFactory.setPassword(serviceBusConnectionString.getSharedAccessKey());
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        var topicFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        topicFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        topicFactory.setSubscriptionDurable(Boolean.TRUE);
        topicFactory.setErrorHandler(priceListErrorHandler());
        return topicFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AzureServiceBusJmsProperties jmsProperties() {
        var properties = new AzureServiceBusJmsProperties();
        properties.setConnectionString(connectionString);
        properties.setPricingTier("standard");
        properties.setTopicClientId(topicName);
        return properties;
    }
```